# Install my self-made scripts to run them from the command-line

Tags: command-line, scripts, execute-command

I have a number of self-made (bash) scripts that I often use. Here are some examples of these scripts:

- A script `backup-system.sh` that backs up my system to an external hard drive.
- A script `repeat.sh` that allows me to repeat a command multiple times. For example, `repeat.sh 5 echo "x"` prints "x" 5 times.
- A script `switch-sound.sh` that switches between outputting sound over my loudspeaker and over my headset.

Because I use these scripts often, I want the ability to easily call them from my command line. For example, I want to type `backup-system` to run `backup-system.sh`.

**How can I install my self-made scripts to run them from the command-line?** Since this is a common issue, I would like to know the standard way to achieve this, that ideally works for many Linux distributions (however, Ubuntu is the priority).

---

**More details**:

- I am the only user of my computer. Still, I would like to be able to use my scripts as both my own user and as `root`.
- I know I could add an entry to `.bashrc` to achieve some of what I want. But because my scripts are often long, this is impractical.

Comment: What do you mean by "because my scripts are often long" (that they consist of many command lines, or that their names are long and cumbersome to type)?

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look into `alias`.

Comment: Rename your scripts to remove their `.sh` extension, put them in one of the directories specified under $PATH, and don't forget the `#!/bin/bash` in the first line on your scripts.